# Error: Unexpected string constant in R function

Tags: r

I am trying to run a function in r starting with the following command:

```
read.tchain<-function("AL1"){
```

and I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "read.tchain<-function("AL1""
```

I have tried multiple variations and no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show reproducible code.  For help in asking good questions see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a function, the arguments should not be strings, so `read.tchain<-function("AL1"){` gives an error. You should instead write `read.tchain<-function(var1){` and feed in "AL1" when you are calling the function like this `read.tchain("AL1")`

Comment: Follow up question - should I run the whole function with the var1 replacement, and then "call the function". Thanks so much for your help! I am very new to this..

Comment: @KestrelKunz Yes you should, if your function actually takes a string as an argument. "var1" is just to tell R that your function takes one argument. You should then replace whatever uses "AL1" with var1 inside your function. Again, you should make your question reproducible by providing sample code and data.